# How to Populate Django Form fields in HTML?

Tags: javascript, python, django, django-models, django-templates

I have a `model.py:`

```
class usercommand(models.Model):
user = models.ForeignKey(User, blank=False)
a_field = models.PositiveIntegerField(null=True, blank=True)
timestamp = models.DateTimeField(blank=True, null=True)
```

Related to i use create Django model form with `user` Input hidden field. `forms.py:`

```
class ApplicationForm(forms.ModelForm):
class Meta:
    model = userCommand
    widgets = {
        'user': forms.HiddenInput()
    }
```

As you can see that there are three fields available for take the input. But i filled the user field in `views.py`:

```
def views_method(request, object_id):
if request.method == 'POST':
    form = ApplicationForm(request.POST)
    if form.is_valid():
        form_inst = form.save(commit=False)
        form_inst.user = request.user
        form_inst.save();
        return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('user_list'))
else:
    form = ApplicationForm()

extra_context = {
    'form':ApplicaitonForm(initial={'user': request.user.pk})
}   
return direct_to_template(request, 'template/remote.html',
                          extra_context=extra_context)
```

Now i used in my `remote.html`:

```
<form action="" method="POST">
{{ form.as_p }}
<input type="submit" value="{% trans "Add " %}" /> 
</form>
```

What i need to fill the timestamp field from template level by using the following picker written in Jquery:

```
<input class="time" type="text" name="start" id="start" />
$('input.time').timepicker();
```

But i am not able to understand, How should i do it? because i am using `{{form.as_p}}`. How will i populate the froms `timestamp` fields with this Jquery code.

If i am not wrong then we can do this by following code :

```
$('#id_timestamp').val($('#time').val())
```

where `id_timestamp` is the id of `timestamp` field in ApplicationForm. But how should i write the code, So that can i can also fill the rest field in `ApplicationForm` at `template` level.

Comment: If I understand correctly, you just need to start the time picker on the actual time field: `$('#id_timestamp').timepicker()`

Comment: @TimmyO'Mahony, Yes we can do by $('#id_timestamp').timepicker(). Here #id_timestamp is the id of timestamp field in ApplicationForm class. What i am not getting hot to use with my Django form ?

Comment: Why are you running the timepicker on a separate field and then copying the result? Why not just run the timepicker directly on the time field in your form? Is the issue you are having that you don't know how to convert the time returned by the widget into a formate compatible with the `DateTimeField`? Otherwise, I don't think I understand the problem

Comment: Yes, I don't know how to run the timepicker directly on the time field in the ApplicationForm. Would you please help me :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<form action="" method="POST">
{{ form.as_p }}
<input type="submit" value="{% trans "Add " %}" /> 
</form>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#id_timestamp').timepicker();
});
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks for replying, If i am not wrong then should i also add the Jquery library path?

Comment: Yes, you will need the jquery library and jquery UI too if you want to use their date/time picker: http://jqueryui.com/demos/datepicker/

Comment: This is an alternative date/time picker library: http://trentrichardson.com/examples/timepicker/

Answer (score 0):

You can use [SplitDateTimeWidget](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/widgets/#splitdatetimewidget) for timestamp field. Then on a template you can acces to time input by `$('#id_timestamp_0').timepicker();` or something like that